# Rails way of representing the Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am removing some hard codings from my rails application.

I replaced the

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>

                   with 
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

Now i have a doubt there are places where i have

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function a()
       { 
          alert();
        }
       </script>
```

Is there any way to do the same using RAILS helpers ???
Please give suggestions.

Comment: For your requirement I dont think any helper exist in rails

Answer (score 0):

There is an helper for that:

```
javascript_tag "alert('All is good')"
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag

Comment: I have javascripts used in each and every view file which has some functions inside it . How to represent them in javascript_tag??

Comment: Put your your_javascript_file.js in /public/javascripts and add <%= javascript_include_tag 'your_javascript_file' %> in the head of your template.